# Put a background when hover a menu item

Tags: html, css

I want to create a `background-color` or `background-image` when hover a menu.

This is a part of my code. So when I hover over the Item C, the background color changes behind the submenu without jQuery.

```css
@import "fonts.css";

body {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0px;
}
.dropdownmenu{
  height: 72px;
  background: #ec008c;
}

.dropdownmenu ul, .dropdownmenu li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.dropdownmenu ul {
  background: gray;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
}
.dropdownmenu li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width:auto;
}
.dropdownmenu a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  display: block;
  padding: 24px 24px;
  font-size: 21px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu:hover a {
  background: #fff;
  color: #ec008c;
}
#submenu {
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 72px;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 235px;
}
li:hover ul#submenu {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
#submenu li {
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
}
#submenu a:hover {
  background: #EEEEEE;
  color:#ec008c;
}
#submenu a {
  background-color:#fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Galaxie";
  padding: 20px 24px 18px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #000;
}

#main{
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center fixed;
  width:100%;
  height:640px;
  background-color:#000;
}
```

```html
<nav class="dropdownmenu">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li class="menu"><a href="#">Item A</a></li>
    <li class="menu"><a href="#">Item B</a></li>
    <li class="menu"><a href="#">Item C</a>
      <ul id="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">Sub Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Item</a></li>
       
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu"><a href="#">Item D</a></li>
    <li class="menu"><a href="#">Item E</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>


<div id="main"></div>
```

**Solution**

```
function chbg(mask) {
    document.getElementById('main').style.boxShadow = mask;
}



<li  id="a" onmouseover="chbg('inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(255,0,0,.2)')" onmouseout="chbg('none')" class="menu"><a href="#">ItemC</a></li>
```

Comment: Isn't that what's already happening? Hovering changes the background color to white.

Comment: Yes , but i want to change the background color in the  `div #main` the black when i hover the item C.

Comment: with pure css this cannot be done due to #main is outside `nav` and cannot be accessed

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking isn't possible purely with CSS.  Because `#main` isn't nested with/a sibling of `#submenu`, you can't select it. The closest you can get is

```
.dropdownmenu:hover ~ #main 
{
    background-color:#cc0000;
}
```

Use some JavaScript to apply a class that changes the background color.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can select parent node with plain CSS, as other said. So you will have to use JavaScript. I used jQuery in my example, although, if you prefer I could use plain JavaScript.

```js
$(function() {
  var menubar = $("nav.dropdownmenu");
  $("li", menubar).on("hover", function() {
    menubar.toggleClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
@import "fonts.css";
 body {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0px;
}
.dropdownmenu {
  height: 72px;
  background: #ec008c;
}
.dropdownmenu.active {
  background: #000000;
}
.dropdownmenu ul,
.dropdownmenu li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.dropdownmenu ul {
  background: gray;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
}
.dropdownmenu li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
}
.dropdownmenu a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  display: block;
  padding: 24px 24px;
  font-size: 21px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu:hover a {
  background: #fff;
  color: #ec008c;
}
#submenu {
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 72px;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 235px;
}
li:hover ul#submenu {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
#submenu li {
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
}
#submenu a:hover {
  background: #EEEEEE;
  color: #ec008c;
}
#submenu a {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Galaxie";
  padding: 20px 24px 18px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #000;
}
#main {
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 640px;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="dropdownmenu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu"><a href="#">Item A</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu"><a href="#">Item B</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu"><a href="#">Item C</a>
      <ul id="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">Sub Item</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Item</a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu"><a href="#">Item D</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu"><a href="#">Item E</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>


<div id="main"></div>
```

I hope this helps you.